# Update table in oracle database extracted from txt.file for every 3 hours

Tags: vb.net, oracle

Update data in oracle database extracted from txt.file for every 3 hours and delete if similar data with same transdate found. Transdate is the date of data being updated into database (today's date). When I run the code it doesn't store transdate. Solution is in VB.

```
Private Sub ReadPosition()
    Dim rowvalue As String
    Dim cellvalue(20) As String
    Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("D:\position.txt")
    'Reading CSV file content 
    While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
        rowvalue = streamReader.ReadLine()
        cellvalue = rowvalue.Split("|") 'check what is ur separator

        ConnectOracle()
        mySQLcmd.Connection = myConn

        If SQL.Length > 0 Then
            SQL.Replace(SQL.ToString, "")
        End If

            SQL.Append("insert into market_one (code, name,location, startdate, enddate,transdate)  ")
        SQL.Append(" values ('" & cellvalue(0) & "' ,'" & cellvalue(1) & "','" & cellvalue(2) & "','" & cellvalue(3) & "','" & cellvalue(4) & "',trunc(sysdate) ")


        Try
            mySQLcmd.CommandText = SQL.ToString
            mySQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

    End While
End Sub




Private Sub DeletePosition()
    Dim regDate As Date = Date.Today()

    ConnectOracle()
    mySQLcmd.Connection = myConn

    If SQL.Length > 0 Then
        SQL.Replace(SQL.ToString, "")
    End If

    SQL.Append("delete market_one ")
    SQL.Append("where transdate = '" & Date.Today & "' ")


    Try
        mySQLcmd.CommandText = SQL.ToString
        mySQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the definition of marekt_one table.

Comment: @dcieslak u mean this?

CODE        VARCHAR2(15)              Y
NAME        VARCHAR2(50)              Y
LOCATION      VARCHAR2(15)             Y
TRANSDATE DATE                       Y
STARTDATE DATE                       Y
ENDDATE DATE                       Y